# Conditional Format top 2 rows of a table visual power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visual with a date column and I have a requirement to highlight the top 2 rows. The data on the table visual is sorted desc by the date column. 
I need help to conditional format the background color for the top 2 rows.

I tried searching for a way to do this but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the rank of the rows and use [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) to highlight the top 2 rows. But first, we need to define what "top 2 rows" means. You said it is sorted by date descending, so I will assume that "top 2 rows" means the rows with the 2 biggest dates. I will use a measure, which will respond to filters applied on the data. Then we will highlight the rows with rank 1 and 2 (assuming dates are unique in table's rows).

Make new measure like this:

```
Measure = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Table'); CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date])))
```

Where `Table` is your table name, and `Date` is the name of the date column. This will give you a number (1, 2, 3...) where 1 is the row with the biggest date, 2 is the second biggest date, and so on.

Then for every field shown in your table, add the following background color condition (right click each item in the list of fields and select `Conditional formatting` -> `Background color`):

[image]

Set `Format by` to be `Rules`, select your measure in `Based on field` and ad condition `> 0 and <= 2` to set the desired background color. Repeat this for all fields shown.

[image]

Comment: For sorting date based on desc order , you have to apply parameter ranking desc also. `RANKX ( <Table>, <Expression> [, <Value>] [, <Order>] [, <Ties>] )` https://dax.guide/rankx/

Comment: That will be needed if it was sorted ascending.

Comment: Got it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I copied the exact steps you've mentioned but I did not get the rank value of 1,2,3,4 instead I got all value of 1. 

I created measure as Rank SD = rankx(allselected(fact_earning),calculate(selectedvalue(fact_earning[startdate])))

Comment: I am getting random rank, here is the screen shot link to imgur.
https://imgur.com/MFCFcSS

Comment: These are not random ranks. The dates in your table are not unique. There are 391 rows with date `12/8/2019`, thus the next row's rank is 392. You must add option `Dense` to `RANKX`. Try to change your measure like this `Rank SD = rankx(allselected(fact_earning),calculate(selectedvalue(fact_earning[startdate])), , , Dense)`.